# How to write mapping conditions in Devart's Entity Developer

Tags: entity-framework, devart

Does anybody know how to use the "Conditions" feature in the "Mapping Details" option of the Model.

I have tried adding Conditions like "IsDeleted = False" or "IsDeleted = 0" and nothing works. Just get errors.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one cannot use a mapped property. Once I removed this, the condition worked. However this means that one cannot update this property via EF, and instead one has to use raw DDL via ExecuteStoreCommand.

Hope this helps someone. It got me scratching my head !!

Comment: We have answered you at our forum: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=27805.